# Juju error: "Bootstrap aborted because file storage is not writable..."

Tags: juju, maas

I have added two nodes in my maas and they both are in ready state. i have also created the file "environments.yaml" and entered the following lines in this file

```
environments:
 maas:
  type: maas
  maas-server: 'http://192.168.216.129:80/MAAS'
  maas-oauth: '${W8QsbnRnV9UZWa28rn:he6edDat92ntkDqCEd:ubRPgpbGpvTHxK9zWNyJ2EgaK6QS5QRa}'
  admin-secret: 'nothing'
  default-series: precise
```

but after that when i entered the 'juju bootstrap' command, i got the following error

```
2012-08-10 01:38:48,519 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'maas' (origin: distro type: maas)...
Bootstrap aborted because file storage is not writable: The supplied storage credentials were not accepted by the server
2012-08-10 01:38:49,721 ERROR Bootstrap aborted because file storage is not writable: The supplied storage credentials were not accepted by the server
```

Comment: Is there any answer to this question? I have the same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

In the Django settings file there's a setting called `MEDIA_ROOT`. It needs to
point at a directory that the user running MAAS has permission to write to.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me like it is an error of the maas-oauth credentials. AFAIK, it should be:

```
W8QsbnRnV9UZWa28rn:he6edDat92ntkDqCEd:ubRPgpbGpvTHxK9zWNyJ2EgaK6QS5QRa
```

without the ${...}, instead of

```
${W8QsbnRnV9UZWa28rn:he6edDat92ntkDqCEd:ubRPgpbGpvTHxK9zWNyJ2EgaK6QS5QRa}
```

Comment: changing this only changes the error